# Trigger a Sitecore Command on a Modal link item

Tags: javascript, sheer-ui, commands

I am working on a Dashboard Popup in Sitecore in which I display list of several items. And I want to know if I can trigger a sitecore command link the "item:load" to focus on the Content Tree item when I click the item based from it's ID.

[image]

Is there a way to do this using JavaScript within Sitecore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a way to specifically trigger `item:load`. But I would probably look first to something simpler, like just generating a Content Editor URL for your item.

```
http://yourhostname/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor?id=%7b9822ABDF-F2B7-41BA-B56D-63E73BEB7E88%7d&amp;vs=1&amp;la=en&amp;sc_content=master&amp;fo=%7b9822ABDF-F2B7-41BA-B56D-63E73BEB7E88%7d&ic=People%2f16x16%2fcubes_blue.png&he=Content+Editor&cl=0
```

Alternatively, with some Javascript:

```
<a onclick="scForm.getParentForm().postRequest('','','','item:load(id={GUID OF ITEM HERE})'); return false;" href="#">Go to item</a>
```

Source: [Link Directly to a Sitecore Item in a Custom Editor](https://firebreaksice.com/link-directly-to-a-sitecore-item-in-a-custom-editor/)